# How to leave the second "in order to", when the meaning can be understood?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-request, phrase-choice, ellipsis

How to leave  the second "in order to", so that the meaning can be understood?

> In order for your scientific article to be accepted and published in one of the authoritative national presses, and **in order** you can use its plus to gain advanced degree, you should know the basis of research.

Are there any alternative phrases for "in order to" that would fit the meaning in this context?

Comment: At the risk of turning this into proofreading, and the style aside, I'd like to suggest dropping *(and) in order* in both places and add *so that*: *For your scientific article ... so that you can ..., you should ...*

Comment: "in order you can use its plus" is simply wrong grammatically (AmE). I don't even know what that would mean.  You must have **to use** (or **so that you can use**. But even then, what is "its plus"? Perhaps an IndE idiom?

Comment: Both AE and BE Dictionaries say that plus  as a noun is used in informal English to mean an advantge,  gain,  or vourable thing/condition.

Comment: _"Plus"_ can be a noun, but it isn't used like that (at least in AmE.)  Maybe: _One plus of having your paper published in an authoritative journal is that you can use it to gain an advanced degree._  **Plus** as a noun means something like "positive attribute."  Not that it _is_ a positive attribute, it actually _means_ "positive attribute."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without making things too complicated,

*...and in order **to use** its plus to gain an advanced degree...*

I'd use here also, *"...in order of using it's plus to gain an advanced degree..."* but having thought a bit, and comparing that to a other more popular example:

*"...in order to do this..."*    OR   *"...in order of doing this..."*

you can see that **TO** is a must.

Comment: In AmE, you would not use "plus" in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

> In order for your scientific article to be accepted and published in
>   one of the authoritative national presses, ***so that*** you can use its
>   plus to gain advanced degree, you should know the basis of research.